# MVC's Kendo UI loses masking on post and on UI.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to mask a phone number in the following piece of code:

```
@Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(model => model.Student.HomePhoneNumber).Mask("(999) 000-0000").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }).UnmaskOnPost(true)
```

So the UnmaskOnPost(true) unmasks the value of the phone number (turns (xxx)-xxx-xxxx to xxxxxxxxxx). This is the intended behavior

However, if there's any validation error in my MVC page, the text box containing the phone number displays the unmasked value of xxxxxxxxxx instead of (xxx)-xxx-xxxx.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use data annotation `DataType`? it is easier and strait forward.

Comment: Yeah :-/ The masking needs to be there. I tried adding that DataAnnotation of [DatatType(DataType.PhoneNumber)] but as soon as I enter, for example, 562-123 and submit the form and validatoin fails, the value on the textbox changes to  562123 (unmasked and unintended behavior). I'm taking care of this in the controller now using RegEx. Wish there was a way.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`to your data annotaion:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(ddd)-ddd-dddd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

change `(ddd)-ddd-dddd`to proper one if isn't correct.

Comment: This also causes the KendoUI's masking ability to function improperly. The numbers show up as (999)-999-9999 but as soon as I change the number on the textbox, the mask of the textbox is gone.

Comment: try removing KendoUI's masking

Comment: Wish I had that option :(

Comment: Delete `.Mask("(999) 000-0000")`

Comment: Yes, I wish I could, but unfortunately I'm locked in to the Kendo UI MVC and I have to use the Mask option. I got this resolved by doing a work-around. I send it masked to the controller and in the controller I use Regex to eliminate any characters that are not numbers.